upstream image response failed for..., "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid - NextJS ImageError
I will be very thankful for any thoughts or ideas about this problem!
In my Next.js 14 project, I'm building a chatting application using Getstream (SDK/API). I'm working on a component to display group chat descriptions, including an avatar image retrieved from the channel.data object provided by Getstream.
Here’s how I retrieve and render the image:
const { channel } = useChannelStateContext();
const channelImage = channel.data?.image as string | undefined;

// image gets passed through multiple components

<Image
  src={channelImage}
  alt="Channel Avatar"
  width={40}
  height={40}
  className="object-cover"
/>

Consider that I also updated my next.config.mjs to include this as a remote pattern:
images: {
  remotePatterns: [
    {
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "dublin.stream-io-cdn.com",
    },
    {
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "img.clerk.com",
    },
  ],
},


Now, as a result, the image actually shows up with no problems on my localhost window. I might've thought that there's no issues, except of the fact that my console in VsCode is complaining:
upstream image response failed for https://dublin.stream-io-cdn.com/... 403
ImageError: "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid
at fetchExternalImage (...)
at async DevServer.imageOptimizer (...)
at async cacheEntry.imageResponseCache.get.incrementalCache (...)
at async (...)
{
  statusCode: 403
}

Here' some of the versions that I'm using:
"next": "14.2.5",
"stream-chat": "^8.37.0",
"stream-chat-react": "^11.23.3",
"typescript": "^5"

I'm concerned about this error potentially causing issues in production or being indicative of some misconfiguration.
Things I've already tried:

I've verified that the image URL loads directly in the browser without issues
I tested with the unoptimized: true option in the next.config.mjs, but then the image doesn't show up

Questions

Why does Next.js log this 403 error even though the image displays fine?
Could this cause issues in production, or is it safe to ignore?
Are there recommended approaches to address this while maintaining performance and reliability?

I will be very thankful for any kind of help or approach towards this issue I'm facing...
